# Insert JSON file in mongodb programmatically

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I created some mocked data in database and export it as json so i can use it for seed, after drop the database. How to import .json file in mongodb programatically
This is json file:

```
[{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5fdb7f818079290de4fffa5a"
  },
  "twoFactorAuthenticationEnabled": false,
  "email": "user@abv.bg",
  "password": "$argon2i$v=19$m=4096,t=3,p=1$zAiJVpwejt30MP8bqOYObA$EfU+wLtFEIMaLRL+dZJRIZqQINNyFy82ptCFxK7RVRQ",
  "confirmed": true,
  "role": "user",
  "walletAddress": "0x8587431eaaDC8756288ef49651f00Dce55F67D7e",
  "privateKey": "0x18025dca0404d5ecffc2f7b2df2fb4c5619434a3810d75c6e8bf42035c9e5f8b",
  "createdAt": {
    "$date": "2020-12-17T15:55:45.989Z"
  }
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5fdb7f828079290de4fffa5b"
  },
  "twoFactorAuthenticationEnabled": false,
  "email": "superadmin@abv.bg",
  "password": "$argon2i$v=19$m=4096,t=3,p=1$H59MQO281W7T3I2nZLv5Qg$Ec9+5cnFJG0yhQqKtZHeNXSp8XjoQs8nnTHl40KPM6U",
  "confirmed": true,
  "role": "user",
  "walletAddress": "0xeE1A85afA7E9D391fC0f740dA45958195f89f053",
  "privateKey": "0x2edb234652d9761906bfd5d75005bab1c57e114ed84cf08134d35452f3b37363",
  "createdAt": {
    "$date": "2020-12-17T15:55:46.020Z"
  }
}]
```

Comment: what do you mean with programatically? you need to use mongoimport, that's all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongoimport/) or create Schema and use it like this:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect(myMongoUrl)
  .then(() => console.log('MongoDB connected'))
  .catch(error => console.log(error));

const myDataSchema = new Schema({
  twoFactorAuthenticationEnabled: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  ...
});

const myModel = mongoose.model('myData', myDataSchema);

myModel.insertMany(myArrayWithData)
```

Without mongoose:

```
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');

const client = new MongoClient(myMongoUrl);

const DB = client.db(databasename);

const myAsyncFunction = async() => {

  const collection = await DB.collection(nameOfCollection); // or DB.createCollection(nameOfCollection);

  await collection.insertMany(myArrayWithData);
};

client.close();
```

Comment: Is there any mongodb example for creating a schema since i'm not using mongoose